# The lyrics of Souad Massi's song "Mesk Elil"; who can help?

Tags: lyrics

Who can help to find the English version of Souad Massi's song "Mesk Elil"?

Comment: A-fan, what do you think of Uri's answer?

Answer (score 2):

There's a translation of the lyrics into French at [this Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/notes/souad-massi-officiel/mesk-elil-traduction-fran%C3%A7aise/10150105816580422). Translated into English, they are roughly:

**Honeysuckle**

In this season when the weather changes every moment
In this season when the leaves wither
When the earth is soaked with the smell of rain
My eyes fill with tears and I think of you

I miss everything, I miss you, and I suffer
And the smell of honeysuckle, I miss it too.

In this season when the sun disappears
When the birds leave their nests
When the earth is soaked with the smell of rain

I miss everything, I miss you, and I suffer
And the smell of honeysuckle, I miss it too.

The streets of my childhood ...
... that I know by heart, I miss them.
And I even miss those who have hurt me

I miss everything, I miss you, and I suffer
And the smell of honeysuckle, I miss it too.